# Accessing the calling object into ajax response... (not the ajax call)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object of type Application (defined by me). Whenever an object of this type is created, it automatically loads a php file say "start.php" using jquery ajax and assign the response to a div say "Respo". Now what i want is to access the Application object from that Respo div. Unfortunately, i have no clue how to do this...
in my ajax call:

```
  function Application(options)
  {
  .......

  var appObj=this;
  $.ajax({
   url:appObj.location,      //Already defined
   success:function(data)
   {
   $("#respo").html(data);
   }
   });
  }
```

Now in my Respo division i want to access that Application object... I tried:
alert(this)
but it resulted in an object of DOMWindow...
i tried editing success function as:

```
  function Application(options)
  {
        .......

        var appObj=this;
        $.ajax({
         url:appObj.location,      //Already defined
         success:function(data)
         {
             $("#respo").html("<script type='text/javascript'>var Self="+appObj+"</script>");
             $("#respo").html(data);
         }
         });
  }
```

But i ended nowhere. :( Although if i assign "var Self='nishchay';" then alerting Self from start.php gives nishchay but i am not able to assign the calling object of Application type to the Self variable. It is the only way I cud think of. :\

Please help me... actually my object has some editing functions to control itself - its look and feel and some other options. I want the code loaded by object to control the object itself.

Please help me.. 
Thanks in advance.
Nishchay

Answer (score 1):

You can pass "this" as the "context" property (jQuery1.4) in the $.ajax then you can access that inside the "success" callback simply as "this", below is what jQuery doc says:

> This object will be made the context
>   of all Ajax-related callbacks. For
>   example specifying a DOM element as
>   the context will make that the context
>   for the complete callback of a request

Here is code example:

```
function Application(options)
  {
        .......

        var appObj=this;
        $.ajax({
         url:appObj.location,      //Already defined
         context: this,
         success:function(data)
         {
             console.log( this ); // will be pointing to the object that you passed as the value of the "context" property

             // YOU SHOULD NOT BE USING THINGS LIKE BELOW
             //$("#respo").html("<script type='text/javascript'>var Self="+appObj+"</script>");
             $("#respo").html(data);
         }
         });
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried this but it helps me accessing appObj in callback function only. In the javascript code defined under "#respo", this points to the DOM Window only... I have tried my best but it always points towards DOm Window...

Comment: I am not clear what you meant by "defined under #respo", a wild guess could be that you store the application object using $.data" method of jQuery to the "#respo" div, something like that $('#respo').data( 'appObj', applicationObject ) and then access it later.

Comment: See... i have an application javascript object...
now in DOM, it is equivalent to an div with class "window" this div has an element "respo" in which i load the content via jquery load.... usually the content is from a php file written by a developer... that php file may have some javascript codes. now what i want is that these javascript codes may access that application object which can handle that dom element of window class. I have written all the code for handling it but the only problem is providing the developer with the application object...

Comment: now ur solution is really gud but since every application has a div with class "window" that in turn have one "respo" division then i cant use jquery.data here... if i used jquery.data then #respo wont refer to a single object... or if there is any way to get the division from which the javascript call is made... then the problem is solved to large extent.. :\

Comment: Not sure whether you have solved it or not, but is it possible to see more code?

Comment: ya check it out at http://webos.nixova.com/System/js/Application.js
thnx for ur time.. :)
and i am not able to solve it till now.. :(

Comment: It looks like the problem is when you are using "$("#respo").html(data)" to insert some content which might contain JS code and when that code will execute it will not have access to the application object. What you need is "eval" which preserves the context where it is executed. Executing script using .html( html ) where the chunk contains some script tags will refer to incorrect "this" -> DOMWindow. Use regex to extract those script tag contents(Prototype way) and then do eval() on them. Also make sure you pass "this" as the value of "context" property while making that Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for this superb solution. I just couldn't guess that I may use regular expressions with context. Let me try, I will get back to you..

Answer (score 0):

```
var appObjPool = {};
var appObjID = 'xxx';

  function Application(options)
  {
        .......
appObjPool[appObjID] = appObj;
        var appObj=appObjPool[appObjId];

        $.ajax({
         url:appObj.location,      //Already defined
         success:function(data)
         {
             $("#respo").html("var Self=appObjPool['"+appObjID+"']");
             $("#respo").html(data);
         }
         });
  }
```

Comment: Hey thnx for this reply and suggestion but I tried it yestreday only(:P) and ya it worked. The only problem is that Self defined here is global (local to Window that's the top level of JavaScript Scope) so if I load say 5 applications then Self would refer to the last application object only... 
This solutions seemed to be working initially but I realized it later... :\

The only solutions I am able to think of is that if there is any way to define Self that is local to each "#respo".... But couldn't get any clue how to proceed... Any suggestion???? It would be of great help... :)